# Vim - YouCompleteMe RestartServer constantly shutting down

Tags: c, vim, autocomplete, ide

I am using vim and its really working great.

However, now I want to try out **AutoCompletion** (mostly using C and golang) and therefore got to know the plugin **YouCompleteMe**.

I read the full instruction and copied them step-by-step so far I understood them. But when I am know starting Vim, I do get the following error message:

> The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with :YcmRestartServer). Stderr (last 30 lines):

Of course I googled it, and I found some closed issues on github, but what I did not find was a solution. There's one statement whose significance I am not understanding:

> You could also force the use of a custom libclang library with -DEXTERNAL_LIBCLANG_PATH=/path/to/libclang.so flag (the library would end with .dylib on a Mac). Again, this flag would be used instead of the other flags. **If you compiled LLVM from source, this is the flag you should be using.**

The **bold** sentence there, does it mean, that I, who don't use the system-clang/llvm (instead the downloaded binaries, **I want semantic support for C**), have to use the *DEXTERNAL....* flag?

I used this command to build the makefiles:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DPATH_TO_LLVM_ROOT=~/ycm_temp/llvm_root_dir . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
```

**EDIT: I opened [this issue](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1685) on github. There are lots of information.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:
`cp ~/ycm_temp/llvm_root_dir/lib/libclang.so.3.7
 /.vim/bundle/YouCompleteme/third_party/ycmd`